# Importing Design Package Caused 401 Unauthorized Error

Tags: 2013

I had created a custom design for a site, and my manager wanted to setup a test site that mirrored production.  The main SharePoint person setup the test site, and gave me full permissions (I'm a web developer, and not a SharePoint person).  I exported the design package from the live site and imported into the test site.  Now I get a 401 Unauthorized error.

I used my test site and imported the design package.  It worked, though my coworker could not view it.  That seemed to indicate to me that it was a permissions problem.  I went to my custom theme and started publishing the individual files which is a pain.  I found the following post which pointed me to use the sitemanager page.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/6a752478-e47c-469d-9cf2-c6737479a979/publishingchecking-multiple-documents-in-sharepoint-foundation?forum=sharepointadminprevious

And I found another page talking about the design packages:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj862342(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj862342%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Based on this, I published all the files that I thought were related to my design package (Master Page Gallery, Themes Gallery, Style Library, Site Assets Library) on the test site in question.

I still cannot go to the root of the site, however, I can view different pages.  For instance, I can view Site Contents and Documents, but cannot view Site Pages.  I can navigate directly to the Home page (SitePages/Home.aspx), but if I from the Home link on the Quicklaunch bar, I get the unauthorized error (_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx).

I figure that there is still something out there that I need to publish, but I just don't know what.  Most of the sites that our SharePoint person deals with are SharePoint 2010.  These are our first sites in 2013.

4/28/2014:  I found this link, [http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/The-page-always-redirects-to-_Layouts15StartaspxSitePagesMyPageaspx-SharePoint-2013-(Minimal-Download-Strategy-Feature)](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/The-page-always-redirects-to-_Layouts15StartaspxSitePagesMyPageaspx-SharePoint-2013-%28Minimal-Download-Strategy-Feature%29),  that talked about disabling the "Minimum Download Strategy" feature.  This seemed to alleviate the issue of access, though I need to test with an account with less permissions than mine.  I don't consider this a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on research and testing, the issue does appear to be the site feature: Minimal Download Strategy.  From August, 2013:  http://corypeters.net/2013/08/issues-with-minimal-download-strategy/

To Disable the feature:

- Click on Tools icon (the cog at the top right).
- Click Site Settings from the context menu.
- Locate the section "Site Actions" on the Site Settings page.
- Click "Manage site features" link.
- Locate the feature, Minimal Download Strategy.
- Click "Deactivate"
- You will be taken to a confirmation page, asking if you are certain.  Click "Deactivate this feature" link.

I'm not thrilled with this answer, but the site is working with a test account of lesser privileges.  Ideally, I'd like to track down the root cause, but I do not have time right now.  Hopefully, this might help others with similar issues.